# pdf data coming back as octet-stream

Tags: node.js, pdf, axios

I'm calling a vendor's API using axios to get a pdf file from them and I need to return it from my own API so that it can be downloaded in the Vue application.

The response.headers from the vendor has a content-type of application/pdf and the response.data I get from the vendor is something like  with a content-type of 'application/pdf'. When I send/return the response.data to the UI, it comes as application/octet-stream, which I assume is expected? How would I be able to convert that into a pdf to download? Below is code from my API.

```
        let config = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer TOKEN_FOR_PANDADOC_REMOVED'
            },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        };

        axios.get('https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents/DOCUMENT_ID_REMOVED/download', config)
            .then(function (response) {
                res.send(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: Here is a solution that tackle a similar problem, don't worry about `vuejs` party https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833420/how-to-consume-an-octet-stream-from-protected-endpoint-using-vue-pdf-a-vuejs-imp/49833421