# How to consume an octet stream from protected endpoint using vue-pdf a vuejs implementation of pdfjs

Tags: pdf, vuejs2, axios, pdf-viewer, pdf.js

I want to use the [vue-pdf](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf) library that is an implementation of pdfjs for vuejs 2.x in order to do the following

- Download a PDF from an oauth2 protected endpoint using axios
- Render the PDF (octet-stream) using vue-pdf library

and the tricky parts are

- Access protected resources
- Render PDF that comes as octet stream

Currently there are no examples in the repo to show case these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around with the library, I managed to do achieve the rendering of a pdf from a protected endpoint using the following approach

1. Make an axios ajax request for the protected resource using necessary auth header and the response type as `responseType: 'blob'`
2. *Magically* create a URL from the downloaded blob object
3. Set the blob URL in a data variable that is then used by `<pdf>` component

I have created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf/pull/83) to the [vue-pdf](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf) repository with a working example. In the PR replace the URL of `axios` request with a REST endpoint that returns an `octet-stream` and you should be all good.

The resulting pdf viewer shown below

[image]